# python manage.py runserver command results in access denied

Tags: python, django

Hi I am new to django and python both.
When I type this command 
**python manage.py runserver** 
from mysite directory (as told in [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/) tutorial) the command prompt shows ACCESS IS DENIED.
I have tried using port no.s 8000 and 8080 in the commmand.

Please Help.

Comment: Please add the full output and if available the full error traceback to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Please run the project in a virtual environment. Will save you a lot of problems.